# Turn a JSON string into a dynamic object

Tags: c#, json, object, dynamic

I'm trying to create a `dynamic` object from a `JSON` string in C#. But i can't get it done.

Normally i would get a JSON string through a web service call but in this case I simply created a simple class which I turn into a JSON string. Then I try to turn it back into a dynamic object with the exact same structure as if it was an instance of the `Entity` class. But that's where I'm having trouble.

This is the class that i turn into a JSON string:

```
public class Entity
{
    public String Name = "Wut";
    public String[] Scores = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};
}
```

Then in somewhere in my code i do this:

```
var ent = new Entity();

// The Serialize returns this:
// "{\"Name\":\"Wut\",\"Scores\":[\"aaa\",\"bbb\",\"ccc\"]}"
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ent);

dynamic dynamicObject1 = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(json);
dynamic dynamicObject2 = Json.Decode(json);
```

When I debug this code then i see that the first `dynamicObject1` returns a `Dictionary`. Not really what I'm after.

The second `dynamicObject2` looks more like the `Entity` object. It has a property called `Name` with a value. It also has a dynamic array called `Scores`, but for some reason that list turns out to be empty...

---

Screenshot of empty `Scores` property in `dynamic` object:

[image: Dynamic object]

---

So I'm not having any luck so far trying to cast a JSON string to a dynamic object. Anyone any idea how I could get this done?

Comment: Is `JavaScriptSerializer` a class of your own devising? If so, could you post the code for `DeserializeObject` and `Decode` and the dependent functions of these methods?

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu No it's not my code, it's in `System.Web.Script.Serialization`. And `Json.Decode` is in `System.Web.Helpers`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
dynamic dynamicObject1  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
Console.WriteLine(dynamicObject1.Name);
```

Comment: Definitely prefer Json.NET to the built-in .NET JSON serialization framework. I think it's easier to work with and based on published benchmarks, definitely faster.

Comment: This is giving me the exact same result as `Json.Decode()`. The `Scores` property isn't an array of `strings`, but has an empty result. Here is a screenshot of the debugged variable: http://i.imgur.com/11Cknbh.png

Comment: @w00 here is the working code **`dynamic dyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"Name\":\"Wut\",\"Scores\":[\"aaa\",\"bbb\",\"ccc\"]}");
            Console.WriteLine(dyn.Scores[0]);`** and it prints `aaa`. How can you say *same result*?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) but deserializing into a `ExpandableOBject`, a type that is native to C#:

```
 dynamic obj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(yourjson);
```

If the target type is not specified then it will be convert to JObject type instead. Json object has json types attached to every node that can cause problems when converting the object into other dynamic type like mongo bson.